# Is there a macOS native MongoDB GUI?

Tags: macos, mongodb

I'm using Robo 3T at the moment, but a bug that will probably never be fixed is making that difficult for me at the moment. Is there a MongoDB GUI that's native to macOS? I'm a huge fan of [Postico](https://eggerapps.at/postico/) and I'm hoping there is something like it available for MongoDB.

I have tried Studio 3T and don't think it works well enough for me to justify the 150$/y price tag (I'm gonna use it commercially). I have also tried compass, which has only renewed my appreciation for native apps. :\

What else should I try?